# Questions about istio external authorization

Tags: kubernetes, authorization, istio, envoyproxy

**Problem statement:**

My goal is to have istio with external authorization service (ideally HTTP, if not possible than GRPC would do as well). There is a requirement to be able to control what exact status code will be returned to client on authorization service. The latter requirement is the most problematic part.

**My research**

- I have read [istio documentation on external authorizer](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authorization/authz-custom/)
- I have made a prototype  with HTTP Auth service, but whatever non 200 status
  code I return from Auth Service the client always receives 403
  Forbidden
- In mesh [config specification](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/istio.mesh.v1alpha1/#MeshConfig-ExtensionProvider-EnvoyExternalAuthorizationHttpProvider) I see the only possibility to set **statusOnError** but it will be used only in case auth service is unreachable and it can not be dynamically changed.
- Also in [envoy documentation for GRPC service](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.16.2/api-v3/service/auth/v3/external_auth.proto#service-auth-v3-deniedhttpresponse) I see possibility to set custom status

  ```
  HTTP attributes for a denied response.
  {
     "status": "{...}",
     "headers": [],
     "body": "..."
   }
  ```

**Questions:**

1. Is having custom status possible only with GRPC auth service?
2. Is istio using envoy API-V3 or API-V2?
3. Any suggestion how to cook istio with external authorizer and custin status codes?

Comment: Hi, Ivan what istio version are you using? This information is required in order to identify which envoy version is being used.

Comment: Hi Piotr, I use latest istio version available with curl -L https://istio.io/downloadIstio | sh -
For now it is 1.13.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the GRPC Auth service prototype and found the answer. It is counter-intuitive but GRPC external auth service  is really more flexible than HTTP one. And it really allows to set arbitrary status code